# getting linker command error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I'm moving some code around and am getting the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_myLocationID",
>   referenced from:
>         -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It seems to have something to do with putting this into a config file but I am just missing what the error is.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import  "myConfig.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

/*
NSString* myLocationID() {
  NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *value = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"EMBERSLocationID"];
  return value;
}
*/
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *myString=myLocationID();
  NSLog(@"Value = %@", myString);
```

the myConfig.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern NSString* myLocationID();
```

and myConfig.m file:

```
#include "myConfig.h"


NSString* myLocationID() {
  //NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  //NSString *value = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"EMBERSLocationID"];
  //NSLog(@"Value = %@", value);
  return @"85";
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Find your target's Compile Sources build phase. Is `myConfig.m` in the list? If not, add it.

Comment: thx - first time using multiple target and that was it. Really appreciate the help. write if answer if you want and I'll accept.